# Is there a way to set a product price to Price On Application / POA?

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, price

I am selling a product that is entirely customisable, based on the customer's particular requirements. It's not something that can be set up as a configurable product - the price would need to be calculated outside of Magento.

So, is there a way of setting up a Simple Product with "POA / Price On Application" as the price?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to create an attribute `is_poa`.

Then on your product page, where it checks if the product is `saleable` you can just add your logic:

```
if($product->getIsPoa()) {

    //do your magic here
}
```

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail, particularly the bit about where it checks if the product is 'saleable'?

Comment: @PhilStewart, Have a look at this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/price_on_application

Although I am not a huge fan of it because you then need to edit a lot of different template files. But it's a good base to work from, always think about flexibility and optimisation